# Illegal character in path with GetInboxRequest

Tags: java, mailinator

I am trying to use the Java API of Mailinator to connect to the mailbox then get a list of messages:

```
MailinatorClient mailinatorClient = new MailinatorClient("myteamapitoken");
Inbox inbox = mailinatorClient.request(new GetInboxRequest("myteamdomain.test.com"));
```

But I constantly get ExceptionInInitializerError caused by

```
Illegal character in path at index 38: https://api.mailinator.com/v2/domains/{domain}/inboxes/{inbox}
```

I have tried replacing "myteamdomain.test.com" by "public" or "private", I have tried adding my inbox to the GetInboxRequest but to no avail, I still constantly get this error.

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Looks like you need to replace `{damain}` with your actual domain. Similar for `{inbox}`.

Comment: I dont really have the hand on replacing those, the GetInboxRequest is supposed build the URL but it just does not.